# Whitelist or white list?

Tags: word-usage

How to write correctly "whitelist" or "white list"? and what about "blacklist"? Is there any meaning difference between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whitelist is one word. If you are using it in the sense of a list of people/things with specific privileges or access. If you are describing a list that is physically color white, then it would be two words.

Blacklist is its opposite. People or things that are blacklisted are not allowed. This is one word. Again, if you are describing a list that is physically the color black, it is two words.

Comment: sounds logically)